# cp seems to not allow --backup=numbered

Tags: macos, command-line, monterey

I am trying a `cp` option that runs fine on Ubuntu:

```
cp --backup=numbered src dest
```

Is there some way to get this to work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

macOS comes with BSD versions of a lot of commands, they usually don't understand options introduced by GNU.

But you can overcome this by installing GNU Coreutils via [Homebrew](https://brew.sh):

```
brew install coreutils
```

The GNU version of `cp` will afterwards be available as `gcp`.